# Is there a simple way to know if my ObjectContext has changed?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is the senario :
I add an entity to my ObjectContext. I have a button. When i click on this button, it updates my database (Objectontext.SaveChanges()). I want to disable this button when nothing has been changed on my ObjectContext.

Comment: With EF 6 and DbContext, you can use DbContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=specs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `GetObjectStateEntries` of the `ObjectStateManager` that is part of `ObjectContext` to check if there are any modifications on the ObjectContext.

Here is how you check for modified Entries

```
var modifiedEntries = MyObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified);
```

You can pass an value of the Enum `EntityState` to the GetObjectStateEntries method to check for other states.